# Show data from two model with same column name same value in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to ASP.NET, I have only experiences in C# Windows Form and SQL Server. Now I have starting my new project in ASP.NET MVC and already have database from my customer. It has two model included some same column name like this:

```
             Table 1
---------------------------------
| Location | Item | Model | Tag |
---------------------------------
|    1     |  10  |  A5   | 221 |
|    2     |  10  |  A6   | 233 |
|    3     |  12  |  A8   | 332 |
|    4     |  15  |  C1   | 223 |

             Table 2
-------------------------------------------------
| Location | Item | Model | Tag | DWeek | DYear |
-------------------------------------------------
|    1     |  10  |  A5   | 221 |  01   |  15   |
|    2     |  10  |  A6   | 233 |  01   |  15   |
|    3     |  12  |  A8   | 332 |  02   |  15   |
|    4     |  15  |  C1   | 223 |  03   |  15   |
```

I just want to show the data which have same Location and Item in one table, I don't know how to query in Entity framework, I have only know how to code by SQL, and I think it seem to be like this:

```
select
    r.Location
    ,r.Item
    ,d.Location
    ,d.Item
    ,d.DWeek
    ,d.DYear
    ,r.Model
    ,r.[Tag No]
    ,d.[Tag No]
from Register r, Due d
where r.Location = d.Location
    and r.Item = d.Item
```

My question is how to query like this in Entity framework for show data in a view, and is it possible to update and create two model in the same time?

Comment: Always use proper **INNER JOIN** syntax. `..from Register r INNER JOIN Due d
ON r.Location = d.Location
    and r.Item = d.Item`

Comment: Shouldn't be much different between MVC and WinForms - can use [LINQ to Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896266(v=vs.110).aspx) with both. **Hint**: the C# code will look very similar to your SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Lambda Expression

```
var Query=Register.Join(Due,r=>r.Location,d=>d.Location,(r,d)=>new {r,d}).Where(
X=>X.r.Location = X.d.Location &&  X.r.Item = X.d.Item).Select(X=>new {
LOCATION_1 =X.r.Location;
ITEM_1=X.r.Item;
LOCATION_2=X.d.Location;
ITEM_2=X.d.Item;
DWEEK=X.d.DWeek;
DTEAR=X.d.DYear;
MODEL=X.r.Model;
TAGNO_1=X.r.Tag_No;
TAGNO_1=X.d.Tag_No;
}).ToList();
```